# Livecycle Designer: JS: find all elements by name

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I have a document in Adobe Livecycle Designer where I have multiple text fields named "Jahr1". They are scattered throughout the whole document.

Now I want to change the value of all those fields. For this I need to find all text fields with name "Jahr1". I tried that like so:

```
var nodes = xfa.resolveNodes("Jahr1[*]");
```

and also like this:

```
var nodes = xfa.resolveNodes("Jahr1");
```

But `nodes` remains empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
 form1.Subform2.Jahr1[0]::initialize - (JavaScript, client)

    // Access a field property using a field name. 
    // Change the field properties of a specific subform. 
    // Use the [] operator to access an object's property.

    // First, get the subform nodes. 
    var oNodes = Subform2.nodes; 
    var nNodesLength = oNodes.length; 

    // Loop through the subform's nodes and look for fields. 
    for (var nNodeCount = 0; nNodeCount < nNodesLength; nNodeCount ++) { 

        // Set the field property. 
        if (oNodes.item(nNodeCount).name.substr(0,5) == "Jahr1") { 

          oNodes.item(nNodeCount).rawValue = nNodeCount;
        } 
    }
```